# Is it possible to use p4bridge.dll in Linux via .net core 3.0?

Tags: .net, linux, .net-core, perforce, p4api.net

I'm using p4bridge in a web api .net core 3.0 application.
On Windows I can execute perforce actions but on Linux p4bridge can't be loaded.

I know p4bridge is a com dll used via p4api.dll, and foreseen this possible problem but I was wondering if anyone succeed this or it is not supported for now.

````
      User profile is available. Using '/home/.../.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: /home/.../source/Sample/dotnet-docker/samples/P4TC/P4TC.API/P4TC.API
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/api/changelist/1/1/2
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
      Route matched with {action = "Get", controller = "ChangeList"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Get(System.String, Int32, Int32) on controller P4TC.API.Controllers.ChangeListController (P4TC.API).
Unable to load shared library 'p4bridge.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order ```
````

Comment: It is not supported by now nor in the future, as Microsot won't bring COM to Linux. Your best option might be interop with Perforce's C++ interface, https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v15.1/p4api/chapter.client.programming.html or its Java API.